# C++ OpenGL, why isn't the vertex array binding the vertex buffer?

Tags: c++, opengl, data-binding, vertex-buffer, vertex-array

I'm pretty sure that the vertex array is not binding the vertex buffer because if I comment out the line where I unbind the vertex buffer it works perfectly fine, which suggests that the vertex array isn't binding the vertex buffer properly.
Here is the code (there is some abstraction around the program and window but it isn't relevant to the question):

```
GLuint va;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &va);
glBindVertexArray(va);

GLuint vb;
glGenBuffers(1, &vb);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vb);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, (2 + 3) * sizeof(float), nullptr);
glBindAttribLocation(program.id(), 0, "i_position");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, (2 + 3) * sizeof(float), (const void*)(2 * sizeof(float)));
glBindAttribLocation(program.id(), 1, "i_color");

glBindVertexArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0); //< if this line is commented out it works perfectly fine

program.bind();

while(window->isOpen())
{
    glfwPollEvents();

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindVertexArray(va);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 3 * (2 + 3) * sizeof(float), vertexes, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

    window->update();
}
```

Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A VAO doesn't store the buffer binding. It only stores which buffer is bound to which attribute. If you need the buffer binding itself (for example, for `glBufferData`), you have to bind the buffer yourself.

Also note, that `glBindAttribLocation` has to be called **before** the program object get's linked.

Comment: does that mean that vertex arrays stop you from having to repeat the vertex attribute code, after the vertex array and vertex buffer has been bound?

Comment: Yes. A VAO stores the vertex attribute settings. Basically `glVertexAttribPointer` and `glEnableVertexAttribArray` (and everything it needs for those commands). You don't need to bind the buffer again, as long as only the vertex attribute settings are used (for example, when drawing). But since you upload new data and need the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding (which is not part of the VAO state), you have to bind the buffer again.